# Getting JSONP response inside a javascript: URL

Tags: javascript, dom, jsonp

This code works:

```
(function() {
        var scr = document.createElement('script');
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        window.insert = function(data) {
                alert(data);
        };
        scr.src = 'http://nocore.info/test.php?callback=insert';
        scr.type = 'text/javascript';
        head.appendChild(scr);
})();
```

It's tested using jsFiddle. What it does is it gets a string via JSONp and alerts it.

And so does this code:

```
(function(){var a=document.createElement("script"),b=document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];window.insert=function(a){alert(a)};a.src="http://nocore.info/test.php?callback=insert";a.type="text/javascript";b.appendChild(a)})();
```

But when I type javascript: in the URL bar followed by this code, I get nothing. Why exactly is this? I'm not aware of any such behavior. I can set window.* variables in the URL bar and I can manipulate DOM.

So what's the problem here guys?

Thanks guys. Appreciate your help.

Comment: It's working. I got an alert says "This is a test" and an script tag in `<head/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`It just doesn't work when you're on Google. I've tried it on a different page and it works.`

It works on Google too. You can found a `<script>` tag in `<head/>`. However, there is no alert window popping up. That's because:

`Can someone please explain why this is?`

Google is using https, and **if your website delivers HTTPS pages, all active mixed content delivered via HTTP on this pages will be blocked by default.** in `Chrome` and `Firefox` (*haven't tested other browsers.*)

That means, if your site runs on Secure SSL, the browse will block some insecure content from external http sources. In your case, that's `http://nocore.info/test.php?callback=insert`. Open you console panel, you will see an error/warnning like this:

```
[blocked] The page at https://www.google.com/ ran insecure content from http://nocore.info/test.php?callback=insert.
```

How to fix:

1. Use another host that supports Secure SSL. `https://yournewhost/test.php?callback=insert` will work. If we are talking about some common javascript library, use a CDN such as Google, Microsoft that support https.
2. Take Chrome for example, disable insecure content check by using a command line parameter for Chrome called "-allow-running-insecure-content". [**NOT RECOMMEND**]

[About mixed content and how to view it - Knowledge Base](http://kb.iu.edu/data/bdny.html)

Answer (score 0):

OK, apparently @Wayne is right. It just doesn't work when you're on Google. I've tried it on a different page and it works. Can someone please explain why this is? How is their JavaScript able to 'disarm' this code?